# Why click event does not trigger?

Tags: jquery

The click event in this code does not want to trigger when I click on any li item, why is that ?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- begin CSS -->
    <!--<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/html5-reset.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <!-- end CSS -->

    <!-- begin JS -->
    <script src="js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--<script src="js/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    <script src="js/myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- end JS -->

    <title>Navigation Menu</title>
</head>

<body style="background: url(images/bgnoise_lg.png) repeat left top;">
<!-- begin container -->
<div id="container" style="width: 600px; margin: 280px auto 0;">

    <!-- begin navigation -->
    <nav id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- end navigation -->

</div>
<!-- end container -->

</body>
</html>
```

myscript.js is located under folder js:

```
$('#navigation li a').click(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

I tried the code in jsfiddle and it work also when I write the script inside the index.html page it work but when I try to link to js/myscript.js it does not work !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run your script when the document is ready or you may move your script at the end, immediately before the tag closing the html body (i.e.: `</body>`)

Another possibility is to use event delegation, attached to `document` (which always exists):

```
    $(document).on('click', '#navigation li a', function(e) {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
```

```js
$(function () { // document ready
  $('#navigation li a').click(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<body style="background: url(images/bgnoise_lg.png) repeat left top;">
<div id="container" style="width: 600px; margin: 280px auto 0;">

    <!-- begin navigation -->
    <nav id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- end navigation -->

</div>
```